# an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, aws-aurora, mariadb-10.4

I am restore a MariaDB 10.4.17 Database to Amazon aurora MySQL 5.6
while creating a table it is showing me this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 25 in file: 'name.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sha2(uuid(),256),
  `InsertTs` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 ' at line 17
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```

error is in the line 'sha2(uuid(),256)'

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Version` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordSalt` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordExpires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ForcePasswordChange` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `Email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NickName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TextNumber` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsValid` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `IsMigrated` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `UUID` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT sha2(uuid(),256),
  `InsertTs` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `UpdateTs` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `PIN` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatestInviteStatus` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatestInviteDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatestInviteUUID` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_User_UserName_UNIQUE` (`UserName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_User_UUID_UNIQUE` (`UUID`),
  KEY `idxPIN` (`PIN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90184 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I cannot figure out what it is on workbench it says
sha2 is not valid at this position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CREATE TABLE will fail because there is no `PIN` column mentioned in `` KEY `idxPIN` (`PIN`) `` line.

MySQL 5.6 does not allow an expression as default value. Use trigger:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Version` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordSalt` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PasswordExpires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ForcePasswordChange` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `Email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NickName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TextNumber` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsValid` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `IsMigrated` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  `UUID` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `InsertTs` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `UpdateTs` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_User_UserName_UNIQUE` (`UserName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_User_UUID_UNIQUE` (`UUID`),
-- -------------
`PIN` INT,
-- -------------
  KEY `idxPIN` (`PIN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90184 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER set_uuid
BEFORE INSERT 
ON Customer
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.UUID = COALESCE(NEW.UUID, sha2(uuid(),256));
```

Comment: sorry I had accidentally deleted a few lines from the create table statement, PIN column is there in the create table, thanks for telling me MySQL 5.6 does not allow an expression as default value.